# Website interface does not appear in recordings and heatmaps

Tags: flutter, clarity

I have a web site, developed in Flutter.

In Clarity, I can't see the interfaces, just a blank screen.

Is this because of Flutter?

I already appreciate the help. :)

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLErx.png)

I would like to know if it is a problem between Flutter and Clarity and so, see if there is a solution.